# Difference between two dataframe and drop those that's not present in both

Tags: python, pandas

State column exists in both of my dataframes, and I'm trying to drop the state that doesn't appear in both.

I've tried:

```
for s in df1_2016.state

if s not in df_2016.state:

print(s)
```

Doesn't work.

I planned to drop it by

```
df1_2016.state.drop('Alabama')
```

Doesn't work.

[image: rmat]

Comment: How do I post my link as an image? I'm new, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: sounds like you want to do a 'inner join'?    https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a couple of dataframes like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'state' : ['A','B','C','D'], 'values' : [1,2,3,4] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'state' : ['A','C','E','F'], 'values' : [5,6,7,8] })

df3 = df1[df1['state'].isin(df2['state'])]
```

df3 will contain the data in df1 where the state is in both df1 and df2 (i.e. A & C)